# Where is it possible to buy an ASIC?

Tags: transactions, mining-hardware, asic, payment, butterfly-labs

I know of Avalon and Butterfly Labs, but they aren't currently shipping. Does anyone know where, if anywhere it is possible to order and receive shipment before the year's out?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, those two are the most advanced, and your best bet is going to be placing an order and waiting for it to ship.  Sadly, as I have one on order and am waiting impatiently.